# What is the value of this Integral? I got it after deriving weber's attractive velocity dependent force.

Tags: integration, quadratics, classical-mechanics

I'm having a very hard time with this integration.

It showed up in the velocity-dependent potential of weber force in the field of classical dynamics.

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{a+x}{bx-cx^2+d}}dx$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: Think about elliptic integrals